# No headphone signal after installing Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: sound

Regarding Ubuntu 14.04
Using laptop and internal speakers are working properly.
Sound card is detected.
When plugging in powered desktop computer speakers to headphone output there is no sound.
Nothing is muted, all volume is up.
Sound Settings automatically set to "play sound through headphones" when I plug speakers into headphone output.
I have purged/reinstalled Pulse Audio

I have purged/reinstalled ALSA.

Still, only internal speakers working properly.

When I boot up windows instead of Ubuntu, everything works fine again.
How can I track down this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem for days, and the solution was to do the following two things:

1. Reset user configuration (as described in the Troubleshooting section of https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PulseAudio), but I guess you already did it when you purged `pulseaudio`;
2. Make sure **Independent HP** is **Disabled** in `alsamixer`. To do that, just type `alsamixer` in a terminal, then choose your sound card (by pressing **F6**) and move to the **Independent HP** column.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Can you give more details on this? My headphone jack wont work after I suspend.